# Move JsValue from one place to another in a JsObject

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "id" : "uniqueId",
  "foo" : [1,2,3],
  "bar": {
    "frob" : "quox"
  }
}
```

And I want to transform it to the following one:

```
{
  "id" : "uniqueId",
  "bar": {
    "frob" : "quox",
    "foo-copy" : [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

What is correct [play-json transformation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) to achieve this?

I've tried the following

```
val moveToObject = (__ \ 'bar ).json.update((__ \ 'foo-copy).json.copyFrom(
    (__ \ 'foo).json.pick
  ))

json.transform(moveToObject).get
```

But that doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: did you try anything? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no **move** transformation, single transformations only (copy + delete). So you need copy `foo` value to `bar\foo-copy` and then remove `foo`:

```
__.json.update(
  (__ \ "bar" \ "foo-copy").json.copyFrom(
    (__ \ "foo").json.pick
  )
) andThen (__ \ "foo").json.prune

scala> res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"id":"uniqueId","bar":{"frob":"quox","foo-copy":[1,2,3]}},/foo/foo)
```